# is it possible that my current chat on whatsapp is visible in my previously used phone?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

last month i have sold my phone to someone.
and now i got the information that my whatsapp chat was visible on that phone.
Now, is it possible that my current chats on whatsapp(the chats on my new phone) will still be visible on my old phone???

Comment: Did you do a factory reset or wipe your device before selling it?

Comment: You should specify which chat application you are concerned about. As long as the login credentials are no longer stored on that phone or you have changed them, any new chat data shouldn't be accesible anymore.

Comment: hey, i am talking about my chats on whatsapp...

Comment: @ChrisF So it *is* relevant. If hitesh didn't factory-reset the device, his credentials are still stored on it. If he didn't even have a lock pattern/pin/password set up, the new owner has easy access to it. So still the question remains, hitesh: **Did you factory-reset the device before selling it?**

Comment: @Izzy - I assumed that he would be seeing other things that would indicate that the new user was logging in with his credentials.

Comment: no i didn't,,,but isn't it impossible that whatsapp is always active on one phone number???

Comment: hey guys,,i just want to know that after i started using whatsapp on my new phone (with my previous contact number), those chats will also be going to my previous phone(handset) or not ???

Comment: If you didn't factory-reset your device, many things are possible – as the new owner has full access to all data you've left on it.

Comment: i am not concerned about the previously stored data(or previous chats),,, i just want to know that my is my current chats (whatsapp) visible on the old phone..??

Answer (score 1):

There are other apps which allow users to view Whatsapp conversations *without* starting the official Whatsapp application. Whatsapp also performs a backup of your conversations and stores it on the SD card (internal or external, depending on device). It's possible that when the new user entered his credentials, the app detected a previous backup and allowed the new user to import the old conversations in.

AFAIK, Whatsapp authenticates the app with the SIM card that is present in the device. So, your  new chats should NOT be visible. In any case, prudence dictates that when selling a phone, ALWAYS perform a Factory Reset AND wipe the data off the internal / external SD card(s).